vbox shows kernel driver not installed and i've not been able to solve this
i've been getting the 'kernel-driver not installed' error on vbox.
i tried this:
sudo dnf install -y "kernel-devel-$(uname -r)"
upon which i get this:
Last metadata expiration check: 0:45:07 ago on Wednesday 22 May 2024 11:01:39 AM.
No match for argument: kernel-devel-6.8.9-200.fc39.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-devel-6.8.9-200.fc39.x86_64

secure boot is turned off too, so i can't seem to figure out where the problem lies or why header files for my specific kernel version are not found.
